# search specif word only from a file using either grep,awk,sed

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

Text File:

```
auto lo eth0 eth0.2 eth0.3
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0.2 inet static
      address 192.168.67.1
      network 192.168.67.0
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      broadcast 192.168.67.255
iface eth0.3 inet static
      address 192.168.68.1
      network 192.168.68.0
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      broadcast 192.168.68.255
```

Extarct only eth0 word only not eth0.2 or eth0.3
Desired:eth0 word,its line number

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` version supports the `-P` flag:

```
grep -noP "(?<=^| )eth0(?=$| )" file.txt
```

Results:

```
1:eth0
3:eth0
```

Comment: Does `grep` really support lookaround?

Comment: @Joey: I can confirm that `GNU grep` does, but only with Perl regex enabled (the `-P` flag). Cool huh?

Comment: In FreeBSD, if you install the [`devel/pcre`](http://www.freshports.org/devel/pcre) port, it gives you a `pcregrep` binary that functions like GNU grep's `-P` option.

Comment: By the way, **+1**.  This would have been my answer if it wasn't here already.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly:

```
awk 'NR>1 && / eth0 /{print "eth0", NR}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$> ... | grep -P "eth0[^\.]" 
auto lo eth0 eth0.2 eth0.3
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Btw,, what do you mean by "extract eth0 word only"? There is -`o` flag, for example:

```
$> ... | grep -o -P "eth0[^\.]"
eth0 
eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess op wanted to match non-aliased, non-lookback interface like:

```
awk '$1 == "iface" && $2 ~ /eth[0-9]+$/ { print $2}'
```

or even:

```
awk -vFS='[ .]' '$1 == "iface" && $2 ~ /^eth/ { print $2; exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Extarct only eth0 word only not eth0.2 or eth0.3 Desired:eth0 word,its line number

Do it with grep:

```
grep -on 'iface eth0 ' file
```

Output:

```
3:iface eth0
```

Append `| sed 's/iface //'` to remove `iface`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v iface="eth0" '$0 ~ "(^| )"iface"( |$)" { print NR, iface }' file
1 eth0
3 eth0
```